# Using UIKit methods in Angular App fails my Jest Test Suite with error ReferenceError: CSS is not defined

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, jestjs, uikit

Versions

- Angular ~16.2.0
- Jest ^29.4.1
- UIKit ^3.17.8
- Node 20.10.0
- NPM 10.2.5

I understand that Node doesn't have access to the CSS API because Client/Server differences, however I don't know how to rectify this issue correctly. I've made a few attempts following similar issues I've found, but they haven't lined up with my scenario.

```
// app.component.ts
import * as UIKit from 'uikit'

...

ngOnInit(): void {
  ...
  UIkit.default.modal('#welcome-modal').show();
}
```

On trying to run my test suit I get the following error:
[image]

Does anyone have any info on rectifying this issue? It would be greatly appreciated as this is getting in the way of the setting up of my pipeline. I can provide more information if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies for asking and Answering is such a short period, however this was what solved the issue for me. I entered the `jest.config.ts` file, added a property for globals and then added the following:

```
globals: {
  CSS: {
    supports: (k: any, v: any) => false
  }
}
```

Adding `CSS: {}` gave the error that supports was undefined so I added that method too. I saw window requires similar treatment so thaat lead me down this path. I hope it helps someone.